# Procedure or function "" expects parameter "", which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

i am new on asp.net with vb.code behind

i am trying get value from sql

my code

```
Dim apps As New MyApps
apps.OpenConnection()

Dim esql As New SqlCommand
esql.Connection = apps.oConn

esql.CommandText = "cekdatauploads"
esql.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Int, 2)

esql.ExecuteNonQuery()
esql.Parameters("@value").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

Dim nilai As Integer = esql.Parameters("@value").Value

apps.CloseConnection()
```

the error is

```
The parameterized query '(@value int)cekdatauploads' expects the parameter '@value', which was not supplied.
```

i already try execute store prosedure

```
declare @p int
exec [cekdatauploads] @p output
print @p
```

and return 0 not empty value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would set the output direction before you execute the command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try by interchanging the two lines.

```
esql.CommandText = "cekdatauploads"
esql.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Int, 2)
esql.Parameters("@value").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
esql.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

one more thing if, `cekdatauploads` is a strored procedure, you should declare it in the `CommandType`

```
esql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
esql.CommandText = "cekdatauploads"
esql.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Int, 2)
esql.Parameters("@value").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
esql.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the CommandType. Stumped me on a copy paste.

Answer (score 3):

You are executing the procedure before you are telling the command that it is an output parameter, by default it assumes it is an input parameter.:

```
esql.Parameters("@value").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
esql.ExecuteNonQuery()
```