# VB.net getting SQL Server stored procedure results

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures, parameters

I want to get the result of my stored procedure (from SQL Server 2008) into VB.net 2012.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[csp_LoginAuthentication] 
    @employeeid VARCHAR (20),
    @password VARCHAR (20),
    @accountstatus INT OUT,
    @logincount INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        @accountstatus = account_status,
        @logincount = logincount
    FROM 
        strato_blueapplesmis.dbo.app_login
    WHERE 
        1 = 1
        AND employee_id = @employeeid
        AND password = @password        
END
```

When I'm executing my stored procedure, I'm getting the results that I want:

[image]

EDITED: Here's my current code thanks to [Steve's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) suggestion below:

```
    Dim sqlConnct As New classSQLConnection

    If sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.Close()

    With sqlConnct.MSSQLConn

        .Open()

        Dim msSQLComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("csp_LoginAuthentication", sqlConnct.MSSQLConn)
        msSQLComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@employeeid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmployeeID.Text
        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text

        Dim accntStat As Integer
        Dim loginCnt As Integer

        accntStat = Convert.ToInt32(msSQLComm.Parameters("@accountstatus").Value)
        loginCnt = Convert.ToInt32(msSQLComm.Parameters("@logincount").Value)

        msSQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox(accntStat)

    End With
```

And I've even tried [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn)'s suggestion:

```
    Dim accntStat As Integer
    Dim loginCnt As Integer
    Dim sqlConnct As New classSQLConnection

    If sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.Close()

    With sqlConnct.MSSQLConn

        Dim msSQLComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("csp_LoginAuthentication", sqlConnct.MSSQLConn)
        msSQLComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@employeeid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = txtEmployeeID.Text
        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = txtPassword.Text

        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@accountstatus", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@logincount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput

        sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.Open()
        msSQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        accntStat = CInt(msSQLComm.Parameters("@accountstatus").Value)
        loginCnt = CInt(msSQLComm.Parameters("@logincount").Value)

    End With

    MsgBox(accntStat)
```

Both codes are giving me an unhandled error for the `msSQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Procedure or function 'csp_LoginAuthentication' expects parameter '@accountstatus', which was not supplied.

I really do appreciate everyone's help here.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Dear God, is that a plain-text password!? 0_0

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: just learning to call SP in VB.net (>_<) Sorry

Comment: If you're just learning, it's worth mentioning that the normal way to return this kind of data is through a result set, rather than output parameters. Also, use a different sample, because plain-text passwords are all kinds of bad juju.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim accntStat As Integer
Dim loginCnt As Integer
Dim sqlConnct As New classSQLConnection
Using sqlConnct.MSSQLConn, _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("csp_LoginAuthentication", sqlConnct.MSSQLConn)         

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@employeeid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtEmployeeID.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = txtPassword.Text

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@accountstatus", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@logincount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput

    sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    accntStat = CInt(cmd.Parameters("@accountstatus").Value)
    loginCnt = CInt(cmd.Parameters("@logincount").Value)

End Using
MsgBox(accntStat)
```

I think that fixes several issues, including: output parameters and setting their direction, a password parameter set as an integer that's obviously a string of some kind, and failing to close the connection in the case of an exception.

---

I also have a serious concern about the original code: it sure looks like there's a plain-text password there. You just don't do that. This is not okay, and needs to be fixed **immediately**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your code but it's giving me the error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll`  `Additional information: Procedure or function 'csp_LoginAuthentication' expects parameter '@accountstatus', which was not supplied`

Comment: Strange, because that parameter is clearly included in the code.

Comment: I've just posted my updated code above. I find it strange too since I've checked some articles and the code should be (or must) working now, but it's not. I think I'm gonna cry (>_<)

Answer (score 2):

You should add also the Output parameters to the collection of parameters

```
 msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@accountstatus", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
 msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@logincount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
```

I suggest also to change the AddWithValue approach. It is a shortcut with numerous drawbacks as you can read in [Can We stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Looking at your edit, I have noticed that you don't execute the command.
After preparing the Command Text, the parameters and set up the connection you should execute the command with

```
 msSqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

after that your output parameters should be ready and you can retrieve them with

```
 accntStat = Convert.ToInt16(msSQLComm.Parameters("@accountstatus").Value)
 loginCnt = Convert.ToInt32(msSQLComm.Parameters("@logincount").Value)
```

Notice that I put the reading the `Value` of the parameter inside a `Convert.ToXXXX` call. This is not required if you compile with [Option Strict Off](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx), but nevertheless, if you have this option set to Off, then it is better to set it to ON. It will help a lot to avoid subtle bugs when the compiler emits automatic conversion from a DataType to another DataType

Finally, the SqlCommand need to know what connection use to reach the database. If you build your command without assigning the connection object then there is no way for the command to execute the stored procedure. You could change the line that initialize the command to

```
Dim msSQLComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("csp_LoginAuthentication", sqlConnct.MSSQLConn )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i tried both of your suggestion. It's no longer giving me an error, but now it's giving me "0" as a result instead of "1". I'll revise my question to show my code.

Comment: Also, I tried to display the result via message box ( msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@accountstatus", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput ) and it's giving me "False as a result.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your patience in helping me. I tried your suggestion, but it gives me an error for the msSqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery(). I've just revised the code above. I forgot to mentioned the I've changed the TINYINT from INT in my stored procedure and executed properly the way I wanted it. I also followed @marc_s suggestion in renaming my SP

Comment: Could you explain what error do you receive in the ExecuteNonQuery line?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery should be called AFTER you have populated the Parameters collection not BEFORE.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: The SqlCommand need to know what Connection to use to reach the database. Change the line to     `Dim msSQLComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("csp_LoginAuthentication", sqlConnct.MSSQLConn )`

Comment: [Don't use AddWithValue()](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @steve: Thanks again. I added `sqlConnct.MSSQLConn` and I just realized that `@employeeid` and `@password` should have `SqlDbType.VarChar` instead of `SqlDbType.Int`. I revised my code and placed the `ExecuteNonQuery()` after the parameters collection, and the error I'm getting now is `Procedure or function 'csp_LoginAuthentication' expects parameter '@accountstatus', which was not supplied.`

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: I'm no longer using `AddWithValues()`, as per advised by Steve, I've just revised my code above.

Comment: I mis-read the post... I came to the question right after you updated, and since I didn't see it in your original code, I thought at first he was saying you _should_ use that function. Glad to see I was too hasty on a second read, and it's always gratifying to see my own article linked :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping me out with the problem, I'm able to figure out the code's issue. I've checked [Procedure or function “” expects parameter “”, which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772328/procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied) and tried replacing

```
    msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@accountstatus", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
    msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@logincount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
```

TO:

```
    msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@accountstatus", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@logincount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

And now it's giving me the results that I want! Thank you again for helping me, especially to **Steve** and **Joel Coehoorn**. Here's the whole code just in case someone might encounter the same problem:

```
    Dim accntStat As Integer
    Dim loginCnt As Integer
    Dim sqlConnct As New classSQLConnection

    If sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.Close()

    With sqlConnct.MSSQLConn

        Dim msSQLComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("csp_LoginAuthentication", sqlConnct.MSSQLConn)
        msSQLComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@employeeid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmployeeID.Text
        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text

        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@accountstatus", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        msSQLComm.Parameters.Add("@logincount", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        sqlConnct.MSSQLConn.Open()
        msSQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        accntStat = CInt(msSQLComm.Parameters("@accountstatus").Value)
        loginCnt = CInt(msSQLComm.Parameters("@logincount").Value)

    End With

    MsgBox(loginCnt)
```